# Facebook Multiple tagging on Photo ios

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, ios5, ios6, fb-graph

I am using FB graph api to tag multiple friends. I am able to tag only one friend. But not getting success with multiple friends.

For single user:-

```
  NSString *photoID=@"23451245";
 [FB_Graph doGraphPost:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/tags/%@?access_token=%@", photoID, @"1235234",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"fb_accesstoken"]] withPostVars:nil];
```

For Multiple user :-

```
[FB_Graph doGraphPost:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"406435626092354/tags?tags=[{\"id\":\"100000947629523\"}, {\"id\":\"100000106756234\"}]?access_token=%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"fb_accesstoken"]] withPostVars:nil];
```

Comment: you didn't mention the issue ... what is happing when you're doing like this ... ?

Answer (score 0):

tags

**Create:**

You can create a **tag** on the **photo** by issuing an **HTTP POST** request to the **tags** connection, **PHOTO_ID/tags**.

**Note:** This feature is intended to help users tag their friends in real photos. You should not use this feature to encourage users to tag their friends if their friends are not actually in that photo, or to tag friends in composite photos. If your app is found to be encouraging this behavior, your usage of this feature may be disabled.

You can specify which user to tag using two methods: in the **URL** path as **PHOTO_ID/tags/USER_ID**, or in a **URL** parameter as **PHOTO_ID/tags?to=USER_ID**. To add several tags at once, you can specify a tags property which contains an array of tags like so **PHOTO_ID/tags?tags=[{"id":"1234"}, {"id":"12345"}]**. Currently, you cannot tag a [Page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) in a photo using this API.

Tagging a photo requires the **user_photos** and **publish_stream** [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/), **publish_stream** is optional - if not present, the tag will go through Tag Review of the tagged person if s/he has this privacy setting enabled. Tagging a photo supports the following parameters.

[image]
**For more details visit [Facebook Developer Site](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/).**